# Reducing number of point features considering minimal distance and spatial distribution

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, esri-geodatabase, fme-form

I have a certain number of generated node features using FME 2016. They are coming as output of one FME workbench and actually representing characteristic points of underground cables. Total number of these points is several hundreds of thousands and, as you can imagine, they are unevenly distributed accross the area of the city.

My task is to reduce the number of points in the way that there are no two points on the distance less than 50 m. Points should be treated equally and they do not have assigned weights. Point features after reduction should be loaded into ESRI geodatabase.

What I can do is to take each of these points at the time and to remove all others in the circle of 50 meters. In that case my only requirement, that there are no two points on the distance less than 50 meters, will be fulfilled, but distribution of the points is in some areas very poor.

What I am thinking of, is there has to be some kind of comprehensive solution which will not analyze each point individually but complete set of features and result is best possible distribution of the points in complete area.

Don’t hesitate to advise me any kind of ESRI tool or even mathematical approach that you can think of, since as far as I see, we do not have built-in FME transformer which will do this job for me.

Current result
[image: Current result]

Needed result
[image: Needed result]

Comment: A screenshot of what you're trying to achieve as well as a screenshot of your FME workbench would be helpful in trying to solve your problem.  When you say 50m, do you mean 50m along the underground cable?  Or 50m in any direction?  I think what you're trying to do is definitely possible in FME, but I think we need some pictures in order to help better.

Comment: Hi @Fezter. Thanks for your response. I just added two screens. I cannot add screen of workbech since I cannot upload more then 2 links, but its pretty basic points generator

Comment: So, just to clarify, you'd like to replace 'clusters' of points with a single point?  Does that single point need to be one of the existing points? Or can it be a centre of gravity or centroid point?

Comment: Its too late now that answers have been added for two products but this is a question where I think the scope should have been reduced to one at the outset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In FME, there are a few options you can use. But, if you want to group points within 50m here is one option:

Use a [**NeighborhoodAggregator**](https://www.safe.com/transformers/neighborhood-aggregator/) transformer.  This will group points within your tolerance.  Connect that to a [**VertexCreator**](https://www.safe.com/transformers/vertex-creator/) which will replace the aggregate with a single point.

I tried this out with 10,000 random points within a square 5km x 5km.

[image]

After running the workbench, it looks like this (grey is original 10,000 points and black is aggregate points):

[image]

Zooming in, you can see it has gathered points together (grey is original points, black is new points).

[image]

Note, the points are not the original points, but centroids of the aggregates.

---

Another method you may want to try is using a [**Snapper**](https://www.safe.com/transformers/snapper/) transformer. You can set a snapping tolerance which will snap points within your 50m tolerance.  However, any points outside that tolerance won't be touched.

Here, red points are snapped, green points are untouched, and grey are original points. You can see that the grey points moved to where the red points are.  Green points are spaced apart enough that they are not affected by the transformer.

[image]

Note, after you run this method, you'll have to process the snapped points to remove duplicates.

Comment: Option with the Snapper works for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Integrate](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/integrate.htm) in combination with [Collect Events](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-statistics-toolbox/collect-events.htm):

- Integrate will snap your point features within a given tolerance
- Collect events will merge your coincident features into one (and add them a weight corresponding to the number of merged features, that you don't need in these case)

Be careful, Integrate will modify your data, so make a backup beforehand.