# How to remove points which are too close to each other?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst

I have a bunch of data points, however I think that some might be too close to each other due to sampling error and could therefore have an impact on my subsequent analyses.

How can I remove data points which are less than 200 meters from each other?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2

Comment: I believe there is an answer for this question already. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208514/reducing-number-of-point-features-considering-minimal-distance-and-spatial-distr

Comment: no duplicate ^^ the questioner is asking for an ArcGIS solution that link you both provided is answered in FME

Comment: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/near.htm

Comment: @ziggy the second answer on that question is for ArcGIS Desktop. It's a shame the scope of that question was not reduced to one product before two were used in answers.